# plot tree with specified branch length and colored branch

Tags: r, plot, tree, draw

I'd like to plot a tree with specified length of branch... I tried with R, but I can try any language you suggest to do what I need.

For example :

```
relationship <- matrix(c(c("a","b","c", 3), c("c", "d", "e", 2), c("d", "f", "g", 5), c("e","j","k", 1), c("g", "h", "i", 0.5), c("j", "l" , "m", 4), c("b","b","b", 10), c("f","f","f",3), c("h","h","h", 2.5), c("i","i","i", 2.5), c("l","l","l",3), c("m", "m", "m", 0.5), c("k","k","k",7)), ncol=4, byrow = T)
#the max length of the tree is supposed to be 13 here... I hope I didn't make a mistake.
mycol <- matrix(c(8, 11, "d", "red"), nrow=1)
```

Here I chose to organize my data as a matrix of 13 rows and 4 columns.
or a csv file :

```
 root, child1, child2, distance 
 a,  b,  c,  3  
 c,  d,  e,  2  
 d,  f,  g,  5  
 e,  j,  k,  1  
 g,  h,  i,  0.5
 j,  l,  m,  4  
 b,  b,  b,  10 
 f,  f,  f,  3  
 h,  h,  h,  2.5
 i,  i,  i,  2.5
 l,  l,  l,  3  
 m,  m,  m,  0.5
 k,  k,  k,  7
```

And a color tools :

```
begin, end, node, color
8, 11, d, red
```

The relationship between the root of a subtree, the first child, and the second are represented as a triangle and the corresponding length value. 
This corresponding value are the distance between the node of the root and the nodes of the children. 
The leaves of each tree are described too with a relationship between 3 values which are the same id.

I'd like to do

```
drawTree(relationship, rotate=T, label="leafandroot")
```

And it returns : [image: this tree]

Or :

```
drawTree(relationship, rotate=T, label="leafandroot", color=mycol)
```

And it returns : [image: this colored tree]

Do you know if a package exists for this kind of plot ? I tried the `ggdendro` and the `tree` packages and nothing seems to do what I need... Any suggestion ?

Comment: Why `ggdendro` wasn't enough? Because the labels aren't in the nodes?

Comment: @TheBiro yes the labels but not just that. I didn't find how I can have a leaf which is not complete (like m in my example) and i'd like to color it... But maybe you saw some options I didn't see ?